# onChange in radio button causing undesired change of values in the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion, reactstrap

```
const [toggleValue, setToggleValue] = useState();
..
..
    {Items.map((item) => (
      <Card onClick={() => setToggleValue(item.id)} key={item.id}>
        <CardHeader text={item.text} />
        <Collapse isOpen={toggleValue=== item.id}>
          <CardBody>
               <FormGroup>
                  <CustomInput value="1" type="radio" id="yes" onChange={handleOptionChange(item.id, '1')} />
                  <CustomInput value="2" type="radio" id="yes" onChange={handleOptionChange(item.id, '2')} />
               </FormGroup>
          </CardBody>
        </Collapse>
     </Card>
```

It works as intended, but when I use the radio button to choose an option in any of these cards, it automatically collapses the current card and expands the first card. The handleOptionChange function which is triggered on making a radio button selection also changes a different value in the state using useState:

```js
const handleOptionChange = (name, value) => () => {
   const Item = name;
   const numericValue = Number(value);
   setFormData({
      ...data,
      id: Item,
      vote: numericValue,
   });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

handleOptionChange(item.id, '1') should not be directly called on onChange

```
const [toggleValue, setToggleValue] = useState();
..
..
    {Items.map((item) => (
      <Card onClick={() => setToggleValue(item.id)} key={item.id}>
        <CardHeader text={item.text} />
        <Collapse isOpen={toggleValue=== item.id}>
          <CardBody>
               <FormGroup>
                  <CustomInput value="1" type="radio" id="yes" onChange={()=>handleOptionChange(item.id, '1')} />
                  <CustomInput value="2" type="radio" id="yes" onChange={()=>handleOptionChange(item.id, '2')} />
               </FormGroup>
          </CardBody>
        </Collapse>
     </Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript event will bubble up to the nearest parent that have a event listener for the event

So in this case when you click on the radio button, it actually trigger an onClick event which bubble up to the onClick event listener of your Card component, thus calling the onClick setToggleValue function

You can add a `onClick={(event)=>event.stopPropagation()}`  to your CustomIInput component to prevent this behavior

Comment: I get event is deprecated error with the 'event' word crossed out in VSCode.

Comment: Sorry it should be <code>onClick={(event)=>event.stopPropagation()}</code>

Comment: This should solve the Card collapsing issue and the other two answers should solve the wrong value issue

Comment: Thank you, this solved the card collapsing issue. However when I use the other two answers, the state values are not getting updated and the radio buttons doesn't click properly.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<CustomInput value="1" type="radio" id="yes" onChange={handleOptionChange(item.id, '1')} />
```

into this

```
<CustomInput value="1" type="radio" id="yes" onChange={() => handleOptionChange(item.id, '1')} />
```

Reason for the cause ,properly

For the `onChange={() => ....}` without `() =>`is same is you will run the function when component mount without waiting for any user action.

You can test by alerting

`onChange={() => alert('will run only when user change')}`

...

`onChange={alert('Will not wait for user and run when component mount')}`

Comment: When I do this, the handleOptionChange function is not called on clicking the radio buttons and the radio values are not set to the state. The radio buttons are not clicked properly I can notice.